# iOS Landscape orientation issue for MonoGame

Tags: ios, landscape, monogame

Used Xamarin 4.0.10 and last version MonoGame for iOS on Mac OS X.
I have a problem with Landscape orientation.

> MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.
>   Name: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation Reason: Supported
>   orientations  has no common orientation with the application, and
>   shouldAutorotate is returning YES

If I add Portait orientation  everything is fine. But I need only Landscape orientation.

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 640;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 960;
graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft | DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight;
graphics.ApplyChanges ();
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
```

This problem is appears after start constructor Game1.cs on the method game.Run()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Info.plist in Xamarin Studio and check 'Landscape Left' and 'Landscape Right' orientation in 'Supported Device Orientations'.